# Assign an array to a property in a Chapel Class

Tags: list-comprehension, chapel

Here is a Python-like pattern I need to re-create in Chapel.

```
class Gambler {
  var luckyNumbers: [1..0] int;
}

var nums = [13,17,23,71];

var KennyRogers = new Gambler();
KennyRogers.luckyNumbers = for n in nums do n;

writeln(KennyRogers);
```

Produces the run-time error

```
Kenny.chpl:8: error: zippered iterations have non-equal lengths
```

I don't know how many lucky numbers Kenny will have in advance and I can't instantiate Kenny at that time.  That is, I have to assign them later.  Also, I need to know when to hold them, know when to fold them.

Comment: To help interpret: The reason you're getting this error is that the assignment to luckyNumbers in your program effectively gets interpreted as: `for (ln, n) in zip(KennyRogers.luckyNumbers, nums) do ln = n" and since luckyNumbers has size 0 and `nums` presumably does not, it's a case of zippering things of different size/length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good application of the [`array.push_back`](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.push_back) method.  To insert lucky numbers one at a time you can do:

```
for n in nums do
  KennyRogers.luckyNumbers.push_back(n);
```

You can also insert the whole array in a single `push_back` operation:

```
KennyRogers.luckyNumbers.push_back(nums);
```

There are also `push_front` and `insert` methods in case you need to put elements at the front or at arbitrary positions in the array.

I don't think I can help on when to hold them or when to fold them.

Comment: Just glad I didn't have to run.

Answer (score 2):

A way to approach this that simply makes things the right size from the start and avoids resizing/rewriting the array is to establish `luckyNumbers` in the initializer for `Gambler`.  In order to do this without resizing, you'll need to declare the array's domain and set it in the initializer as well:

```
class Gambler {
  const D: domain(1);          // a 1D domain field representing the array's size
  var luckyNumbers: [D] int;   // declare lucky numbers in terms of that domain

  proc init(nums: [?numsD] int) {
    D = numsD;                 // make D a copy of nums's domain; allocates luckyNumbers to the appropriate size
    luckyNumbers = nums;       // initialize luckyNumbers with nums
    super.init();              // mark the initialization of fields as being done
  }
}

var nums = [13,17,23,71];

var KennyRogers = new Gambler(nums);

writeln(KennyRogers);
```

Comment: You could also take @david-iten's approach of using push_back() within the initializer itself (in phase 2, or after the call to `super.init()` since it's operating on the array, not simply initialize-assigning it).  The tradeoff would essentially be that push_back()-based approaches are going in incrementally build up the array requiring (amortized) reallocations of it whereas the approach proposed here will simply "make it right the first time."

Comment: Is the memory cost only during the initial construction, or does it somehow create problems down the line?  For instance, I won't be adding to `luckyNumbers` again.  Am I losing any efficient later?